# PouchDB authentication triggering CORS preflight request

Tags: javascript, cors, couchdb, pouchdb, preflight

The following code (using the [PouchDB Authentication](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication) plugin) fails because it triggers the browser to send a CORS preflight request, and CouchDB does not support the `OPTIONS` HTTP method.

```
var db = new PouchDB("http://localhost:5984/mydb");
db.login('username', 'password');
// assume the database URL and login info are valid
```

Here is the error (in Chrome). Note that this issue also occurs in Edge, but not in Firefox:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5984/_session. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

And here are the headers that Chrome is sending for the request (they are not significantly different in Firefox):

```
POST /_session HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 25
Accept: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es-419;q=0.6,es;q=0.4
```

I have already enabled CORS via the [`add-cors-to-couchdb`](https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb) Node script. Things I have tried:

- Manually adding `OPTIONS` as a method under `[cors]` in my local.ini
- Passing `{ ajax: { content_type: "text/plain" } }` as the third argument to `login`

So, my question is:

- How can I prevent the preflight request from being triggered? Looking at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), it doesn't seem necessary.
- If the previous is not possible, how can I set my CouchDB server up to respond to preflight requests?

Answer (score 3):

Hitting this same issue.  Seems Chrome has recently started being a little more aggressive about sending the OPTIONS preflight.
A partial work around was to specify a specific origin in the CORS header instead of '*',
so

```
curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/origins -d '"localhost:8080"'
```

or similar.

I still am getting the preflight error, but now PouchDB successfully authenticates, so I can just ignore the error.
I think the fix is to get CouchDB to respond to OPTIONS on the _session url.

Edit, more info here
https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication/issues/111

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, when I tried specifying the origin as you describe, the result was the same as before (same error, no authentication). Also thanks for the link, the information is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

With the latest PouchDB you authenticate like so:

```
var remote = new PouchDB("http://user:password@localhost:4984/bucket/");
```

Comment: Never authenticate like this - the credentials are in plain site.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to hide this.